# How do I install IIS on windows xp if it doesn't show up in add/remove programs?

Tags: windows-xp, iis

I'm trying to install IIS on Windows XP Professional SP3, but it isn't listed in add/remove windows components. How do I add the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There is a file C:\windows\inf\sysoc.inf that controls what shows up in the add remove programs menu.

In the [Components] section of sysoc.inf there was a line for iis:

```
iis=iis.dll,OcEntry,iis.inf,**HIDE**,7
```

Removing hide from this entry allows it to show up in the add/remove windows components dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from Microsoft: [Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.5 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good link. I didn't know there was an express version of iis. I managed to get the real thing running though.

Answer (score 1):

We need the installation CD of Windows 2000 Professional or Server

2. Copy the directory i386 from the WinXP Home to your hard disk (If you don’t have 2 CD-ROM)
3. In this directory (i386) there is a file called `IMS.CAB`. Open it with WinRar (or something similar) and unpack the content to a temporary folder (you will need them at the end of the installation)
4. Search for and find the file: `c:\WINDOWS\INF\SYSOC.INF`
5. In the section `[COMPONENTS]` you will find this line:

   ```
   iis=iis.dll,OcEntry,iis.inf,hide,7
   ```
6. Change it to this:

   ```
   iis=iis2.dll,OcEntry,iis2.inf,,7
   ```

   (remember to change the name in iis2.dll and iis2.inf and to eliminate the word hide. In this way you bypass the protection of XP home)
7. From the Win2000 cd (Pro or Server) take the files: `iis.dl_` and `iis.in_` that are in the `i386` folder and copy them on your desktop,
8. Open a dos windows and with the prompt pointing at your desktop edit the following commands:

   ```
   EXPAND IIS.DL_ IIS2.DLL
   EXPAND IIS.IN_ IIS2.INF
   ```

   this will generate two new files named `iis2.dll` and `iis2.inf`. Copy and paste

   ```
   IIS2:DLL to c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SETUP\
   ```

   and

   ```
   IIS.INF to c:\WINDOWS\INF\
   ```
9. Go to control panel => windows components, you will see `Internet Information server` is now available as a checkable option.
10. Select it (I suggest that if you are looking only for `PWS` to select only that because the more components you install the more files you have to search for)
11. It will need a few minutes and during that time the system is going to ask you for a lot of files: some are in **XP Home CD** other in **Win2000** CD. At a certain point the system will ask you for the `EXCH_adsiisex.dll` file. This is the file you have extracted in *step 2* of this guide. Select it and you should go on without trouble.
12. At the end restart your computer.
13. To test if it is working, open Internet Explorer and type in the address line:

    ```
    http://localhost
    ```
14. If it doesn't work, try the following:

    1. Open a DOS window and type:

       ```
       iisreset /RESTART
       ```
    2. Go to web properties in **directory protection** (I don't know if this is the exact name on an English version) click on **modify** (or edit, as said before I don’t have an English version) **browse** and finally **find**. You will see all users in your PC.
    3. Select the one you are working with and click OK. In the text-box you will see `PcName\UserName`.
    4. Click OK to close the window. Remember to uncheck **password Control** and click OK three times.
    5. Close and restart the web server and retry *step 12*. If all is correct you will see the default presentation page of IIS and the online help.

Comment: It works! Very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

The link @JohnDR provided is a snapin for the IIS management console that will permit remote IIS management from XP. It will not install IIS in your XP environment. For that have a look here. You have to install a few components prior to going to add/remove programs.

[Installing IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/iiiisin2.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Your right I did have wrong link its fixed now.